# WkHtmlToPDF displays a tiny pdf if text is too long

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am not sure how to overcome this problem even though I have set the page size to be A4, I would assume that my page size would remain intact and my content would be wrapped correctly?

*note* I am using the wrapper **WkHtmlToXSharp** to create my pdf

[image]

Issue: If you enter strings that are not split, i.e. one long string - what I have showed in the image above will occur. How do I fix this? Is there some options for WkhtmlToPDF to wrap the text?

Comment: I just added a question very much related to this, but it deals with images instead of long "unbreakable" strings. I believe the underlying reason to be the same but the solution to be different. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12456736/694325

Comment: Just looked at your question - not sure how many workarounds are available for this tool. People have suggested a javascript fix i.e. count chars and break up each line, but I cannot honestly say what the best solution is. Looking at google docs it seems as though they break up each line but looking at the width of page and the width of chars then doing some split - but I cant say for sure. Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: hi, were you able to get this fixed? I'm facing the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: @sash nothing yet... I used another library as I could not figure it out. (fo.net)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a CSS solution, you could try setting a width for the element that overflows and then testing with `word-wrap: break-word;`, `overflow:hidden;` and `white-space: nowrap` to control the issue, some of these or a combination might work for you. As for a wkhtmltopdf solution that would be universal... If you find any, I want one too!

Comment: As for manually hacking the source HTML, you could load it to a string and then check if there are any words that are longer than 9000 characters and then execute the dirty hacker responsible - but that method seems icky to me. Even a JS solution might actually work for that route if you don't want to do it in C#

Answer (score 1):

This is the css I'm using in gimli (https://github.com/walle/gimli) to fix this issue.

https://github.com/walle/gimli/commit/39981dda4de003902748c3e089aa42da809af6a9#L0R145

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the pages. It's easy as adding this:

```
<div style='page-break-after:always'></div>
```

For example, if you have a long table, you can do like this pseudo-code:

```
 if ($row > 100) {
   echo "</table>"; 
   echo "<div style='page-break-after:always'></div>";
   echo "<table>"; }
```

Comment: My issue is more related to text wrapping not page breaks

Comment: Ah, now I got it - well, that's a tough one - my thinking is to read the strings and if it's too long, break it with dashes using one of the string functions. PHP has "wordwrap()" function. Don't know about C# tho.